# ASP.NET 1.1 Page_ClientValidate Debugging

Tags: asp.net, debugging, asp.net-1.1

I have an ASP.NET 1.1 application, and on my local machine the submit button on my page works fine, but when I deploy it to our development application server, I click on Submit and nothing happens.. I'm assuming that the Page_Validate() function is failing and disabling the POSTBACK, but how do I debug this and determine what is failing?  It sounds like some config problem since it works great on my local machine but not on the remote server...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happened... in ASP.NET 1.1, there was an error in the WebUIValidation.js file (supplied by microsoft and created when you run aspnet_regiis.exe), in function ValidatorCommonOnSubmit.  It seems the method was missing a return statement!! If you modify this file and insert "return event.returnValue" at the end, your validations are OK.  Took me a while to find this one, but once I did I googled it and it was a well known bug.

Answer (score 0):

I remember back in the day with 1.1 Visual Studio used to destroy my event handler hookups occasionally.

If you are using Visual Studio 2003, make certain that the "generated" code still contains the event handler wireup for your control.

Answer (score 0):

See if the aspnet_client directory of scripts is correctly installed on the server. You should have a js like [this one](http://www.eaglemp.co.uk/aspnet_client/system_web/1_1_4322/webuivalidation.js). Otherwise execute `aspnet_regiis.exe -c` (see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.71).aspx))